# Maximum number of entity you have ever used for entityframework in your projects?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

We have a 500+ tables in our sql server database.

We want to update our project to new generation techniques. We want to use entity framework as ORM for DAL. We started to develop small modul of project with  c# -> asp.net -> mvc3 ----soa-- wcf -> (Repository Pattern) EF.

Almost we used 50+ entity in entity framework in the initial project. The performance seems good. But we are worried about how performance will be, if entity number will 500.

What do you advice to us?

Comment: I assume you want to keep working database-first?

Comment: What are your concerns about using an ORM? What sort of environment are you running in? You will find that with 500+ tables the startup time for EF will be extremely large. Also if you are trying to pull out a large amount of data from the database, you will have issues with memory (since you need to allocate all the memory to store the objects you pull down). However at the end of the day what do you call "performant"?

Comment: Yes we are using database-firt approach. We are developing ERP software CRUD application. Please give an example for environment that you asked.

Comment: btw although your solution is DB first, you can test Code first and 1000 tables using a t4 template or your favourite code generator fairly quickly to confirm all ok

Comment: I'm not very good at t4 template. Can you send link sample project for this 1000 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont see any issue with 500.  Although i have only test 200 so far.

Firstly you are not compelled to use MEGA contexts each time you access the DB.
[use bounded contexts as an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx)
You can have 1 large context for migration pruposes. Once off.
Then smaller access only contexts for everyday use.

EF 6 offers even better support in this area, making it easier to have multiple contexts.
[EF 6 specifications - see Multiple Contexts per Database](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Roadmap)

Then look at performance notes on EF.
[performance notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327.aspx)
and [more performance notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853)

You can also generate compile VIEWS on contexts, improving initially loads.
See EF powertools [ef Powertools for VS](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Your advices seems very nice. I will investigate your url links. Thanks. I will wait this kind of answers.